Job title doesn't match my work
My job title is something scientific like "Biochemical Engineer" but as a person with strong computer skills broadly, I spend most of my time (~80%) doing a mix of software development, maintaining on-premise servers, networking, database management, and similar stuff. I end up working in-between the software and science teams at the company a lot. I like the work and it pays well, but the situation feels bad professionally. My issues are:

My boss is happy I'm doing this so that others don't have to, but has no idea what I'm doing 90% of the time. I feel this strains our relationship and I don't get mentorship.
I feel that computer work is undervalued by the scientists in the company, putting me at long odds for promotions and career development within my current team.
The computer work makes it hard to keep up with the scientific work, furthering the divide. Tech leads in the science team don't come to me for new projects or related work, leaving me to "do my thing", and I feel I have to put a large effort in keeping myself included.
At some point the company will probably need "real" dev-ops and IT people, at which point I may be left out in the cold.
For future jobs, I'm either lacking in the skills expected of other "biochemical engineers" or I will have to convince recruiters that actually I'm a good software developer or similar despite my lack of title & training.

It's obvious to me that the situation overall is affecting my happiness/anxiety levels and I should find a solution. I would appreciate others perspectives on whether these concerns are reasonable or not.
I feel my general options are:

Leave (duh, but see 5. above).
Ask for a promotion / different title or better recognition within the science team. I'm not exactly sure what title/role I could reasonably ask for. I could make up a title which would seem better and reflect the multidisplinary nature of the work but I'm not sure if management would be open to that or if it's a good idea.
Ask for a transfer to the software team. The software team might be a better fit but doesn't currently have any explicit openings I'd fit in, but I'm on good terms with the software team management.

I would appreciate other perspectives on my options, if I'm missing anything or if there are other things I haven't considered.

What's your personal long-term goal? Would you rather be doing real biochemical science, or be doing more IT and computer software?

I don't know, but I guess that's my real problem.

The job title on my resume is generally meaningless. Every company does titles differently. The bullet points under that title explain who I am and what I can do.

I think here the anxiety is getting the best of you.  I would summarize your email as this:  "My boss likes me, and I am well compensated.  My problem is I am unsure of my future".
The bottom line is that it sounds like you are killing it.  When a reasonable person hears the job title "Biochemical Engineer" the stereotype will be that the roles are filled by really smart people that might not be the best socially.  That kind of thing will explain issues 1 through 3.
If they do bring in a dev team, your role will be invaluable serving as a bridge between that Bio team and the software developers.  That would more likely lead to a promotion and would certainly help management see your worth.  If I was leading the dev team, we would have frequent meetings.
My advice to any engineer is to learn some software development.  Those that don't have more difficulty finding work.  You are a valuable resource and with any kind of engineering you have to continue to learn.  I think the job market would be hot for you.  You may have trouble getting work as a "web developer", but so would I despite being a software engineer for 25 years.  My focus is on other things and UI work sucks anyway.
My advice is to relax and stay.  You may have a little bit of depression or fear of success going on.  You may want to see someone about that.  Yep, that is my biggest advice for you see a mental health professional.  Your life is good, and you should be happy.
Do the other things too.  Pay down your debt, contribute to your 401K (assuming US), and in 25 years or so you will be a wealthy individual for doing just those things.

It really comes down to your goals, short and long term.
Getting past the ego part of what someone's title is, what is it's use?

Recognition in your current job
On your resume

Getting back to your goals. That is where matching up your role to your title gets meaningful.
You've done a good analysis of different reasons for matching the title to the role.
So, where do you want to be in 3 or 5 years?
If software is where you want to be and what you really enjoy, then ask for a title reflects it. You can be a SME (Subject Matter Expect) in the science as well. That is value-add.
There usually isn't a harm in discussing long term goals with your boss. The key thing is don't get them scared that you're going to jump ship.

Sammy, you seem like you're pretty competent at what you're already doing.  If you want more structure, it would be easiest for you to transition to a bona fide software development role in a scientific environment.  Your current job is sort of a dead-end spot because they like the work you're doing but it's not the correct kind of work to promote you as a bio-engineer.  It doesn't sound as if the company has a real IT staff, so a lateral job change is out of the picture and you could be easily stuck where you are forever with real challenges for ever making more money or a career path because your bosses don't understand the work.
Work with your strengths :)

Realistically, exact title rarely matters. People will be more interested in what your skill sets are and what you've actually done than in what label you happened to be wearing at the time.
In some companies part of the title may indicate seniority and/or salary band, but those terms aren't always used consistently and don't directly translate between companies -- sometimes not between divisions within a single company.
Focusing on what you want to do with your career, rather than what you're called, is a lot more productive.
(The only time I've ever been disappointed in my title was that, when I left the Research division, it changed from Scientist to Engineer. My childhood goal was to be a Scientist, and I liked being able to call myself one. Even if what I was doing really was engineering.)

NO, this is incorrect.  Titles matter when one CHANGES jobs.  You could accept a job as a junior engineer, learn all the responsibilities of the junior and senior roles.  If there's never a promotion, and you're looking for a senior role, an unwitting resume screener may flag a resume if the hiring manager says they only want applicants who have actively been in a senior role already -- despite whatever experience the resume may convey.

@xavierj: Years and roles and keywords are more important, in my experience. Especially now that resumes are being machine scored. But gods know the few times I was involved in interviewing, I completely ignored title. Among other things, the definitions of title terms are not standardized; I can tell you from experience that "Master Electrician and Lighting Crew Chief" may mean "only electrician and entire lighting crew "
